# How can I solve CloudFlare Captcha?

Tags: web-scraping, captcha

guys.

I have faced some problems while am developing the website to scrape data from a website.
This website has a CloudFlare Captcha. I am terriable.
I used the api which 2Captcha.com provide, so I could get the token to bypass the CloudFlare Captcha, by the way I don't know how to jump the page, which I want, with the token.
Any helps would be appreciated, Please help me!

I tried to get the token from 2Captcha.com, so I could get the token.
But I can't jump next page with the token, how can I do now?
Please help me!

Comment: hi, was there an error issue

Comment: Nope, there is any error. I can get right token from 2Captcha.com, by the way I can't find the callback function and I don't know how to run the callback function.

Comment: I think not getting detected at first point (==> no captcha needed) would be the easier way. You can try usin [Selenium-Profiles](https://github.com/kaliiiiiiiiii/Selenium-Profiles) or undetected-chromedriver

Comment: I am using ruby, and I don't like to use Selenium cus it is so slow. plz point me the other way !